# Display different rows of a record in a single row having all the column values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 ,

I have an Orders table where it lists two records with different column values.

For ex:

### OrderNumber - SalesNumber - Success/Fail

#### 91010        ---      Success

#### 91010       4786     ---

I need to display this as a single row.

### OrderNumber - SalesNumber - Success/Fail

#### 91010 -   4786 - Success

Is this possible using SQL Query. How to do that?. Please Suggest

Comment: So every `OrderNumber` always has 2 rows, with one field null in each?

Comment: Exactly. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ordernumber, max(salesnumber), max(successfail)
from yourtable
group by ordernumber
```

Comment: It Worked perfectly. Thanks much. But this will work only if the value is NULL in each. Isnt it?.

Comment: Not exactly. If, say, `salesnumber` is not null in both rows, it will still show only the maximum value. But is that likely to happen in your case?